# Spring integration file watcher

Tags: java, file, spring-integration, file-watcher

I am using spring integration for file watcher and I am successfully able to poll file in the specified time. But I want to look into the specified directory and get the list of files and process them rather than processing individual files .below is the code snippet

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processFileFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
    .from("fileInputChannel")
    .handle("fileProcessor", "process").get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel fileInputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

```
public class FileProcessor {

    public void process(List<File> files) { // I want this method to accept list of files
        //here I want to get list of files but I am always receiving individual files only 
    }

}
```

I tried by adding FileListFilter which will return list of file , but process() is not picking list of files as arguments , but only individual file is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to have a directory as an input and do file listing yourself, then you must not look into the `FileReadingMessageSource` and its `WatchService` feature.

Your `process()` may just receive a `File` object as an input dir,  then you call its `public File[] listFiles() {` and do whatever you need according to your logic.

You also may use `java.nio.file.Files` features for your task.

I mean there is nothing sophisticated with just listing the files from dir to justify the fully-blown Spring Integration component.

Comment: Thanks for the  response , but how do we call public File[] listFiles(){ }, I am new to spring . can you please share me an sample or example for it

Comment: I'm not sure what you see as Spring'y in just plain `java.io.File.listFiles()`. See a general Java tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-directory-files